# Characteristic length for the given problem of heat transfer

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer

In the following problem of heat transfer, what does characteristic length actually mean? In this problem, they have found the heat transfer coefficient (h) separately for the vertical and horizontal surface with the characteristic length being the height and width, respectively. Is it okay to take the length of the duct as characteristic length? If yes how should I proceed to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: You show a problem with a given solution...

Comment: @SolarMike I want to know why the height and width are taken as characteristic length?Can we take length (15 metre) as characteristic length?Actually i am not clear with the idea of characteristic length except for that in Reynold's number it is (4*A)/P.

Comment: Go back further in the chapter...

Comment: @SolarMike in the text book its simply given as Le=(4A/P) for rectangular sections which would become Le=2hw/(h+w). There is nothing much in the text other than this...

Comment: Without getting my book out, I think you are reading it wrong. There is usually a description before the definition of 4A / wetted perimeter...

Comment: @SolarMike I don't think I can find anything relevant to this problem... Although it has given the Lc to be used in certain cases..

Comment: The usual bit says that the characteristic length is the diameter... If you have not read your textbook enough then try this in wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_length

Comment: @SolarMike I guess you are emphasizing the fact that since it's diameter it can't be length of the duct as cross section of duct is height*width in this case.But in the case of a vertical cylinder we take the height(or length) of cylinder as Lc rather than diameter D.Whereas in a horizontal cylinder it's Lc equals diameter.

Comment: Perhaps you are reading it then... Book I like is heat transfer by Simonson... **well worth buying**...

Comment: @SolarMike My previous comment about Lc of vertical and Lc of horizontal pipe was a question actually.Why does it differ when orientation changes?